# I need help in evaluating the errors in a range and calculate the average of the cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following data in the range....

```
74.94157    #N/A    76.33115
```

at cells C10, D10 and E10 respectively. I need to calculate the average after checking for errors.

I used the following formula....

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(IF(ISERROR(C10:E10),FALSE,IF(C10:E10="",FALSE,C10:E10))),C10:E10)/SUMPRODUCT(--(IF(ISERROR(C10:E10),FALSE,IF(C10:E10="",FALSE,C10:E10))))
```

But still, gives me N/A as the answer. Where I went wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have Excel 2010 or later use AGGREGATE:

```
=AGGREGATE(1,6,C10:E10)
```

[image]

---

If not use this array formula:

```
=AVERAGE(IF(ISNUMBER(C10:E10),C10:E10))
```

being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of enter when exiting edit mode.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. May be I can use Aggregate but issue is this file will be used by plenty people and everyone does not have 2010 version. And most of all my windows server 2008 does not have 2010 excel. I do not want use control-alt-enter array formulas. If that is the only option then I have to use that one only. I had already figured the above said example. Thanks for your help. I just wanted use double unary option.

Comment: @user2355433 good luck, I could not make Sumproduct work.  If you do, please put it as an answer.